# Reading multiple files from S3 into pyspark when bucket structure is non trivial

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark

The text files in my AWS S3 bucket are organised as follows:

```
my_bucket
    all_files
        folder1
            1a.txt
            1b.txt
            ...
        folder 2
           2a.txt
           ...
```

In short, the bucket contains one main folder which contains several sub-folders, each of which encloses a bunch of files.
I wonder whether there is a performing way to read all this text files in a RDD with pyspark.

I've tried a wildcard solution

```
 sc = SparkContext()
 sc.textFile(bucket_URL + '/all_files/\*')
```

but this throws a 'path does not exist' error:

> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist

Comment: The triviality of the bucket structure depends on you. A naive and straightforward solution would be to use the AWS S3 sdk to mimic your bucket structure. Isolate the files to read and iterate over them to create a Sequence of RDDs. Once you do that, you can union all RDDs.

Comment: @eliasah that's exactly what I did, but I was wondering whether there is a more straightforward solution

Comment: Unfortunately there is no magic here. You'll need your files tree and a simple transversal read.